# Futuristic novel in which pharmacists are the most important people in the world

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember very little of this book, except that I enjoyed it very much. The only thing I remember is that the most important people in the book are the pharmacists. It's a futuristic novel about a couple on some sort of quest and the woman gets injured so they must find a highly honored pharmacist.

I read the book about three or four years ago. I got it from the library and it was just a single book, not part of a series. Instead of futuristic, a better description is post-apocalyptic.

It was not part of an anthology. The age range, due to the violence, was probably 14+. I remember how desperately they needed to find pharmacist. Pharmacists filled the role of doctors. There was one famous pharmacists in the area. When they found him his house was a large rambling place with guards and a fence around it, I think. After a little while talking to him and getting the medicine he asked them to do something for him which was like black market. The pharmacist was really hot on the woman.

I read this book about four years ago as an e-book from the library. I have no idea when it was published but it had the feel of a modern publication, late 1900s or post-2000. A better word for it than futuristic is post-apocalyptic. It was not part of an anthology. The Reader's age range, due to the violence, was probably 14+. I remember how desperately they needed to find a pharmacist because our heroine was injured. Pharmacists filled the role of doctors. There was one famous pharmacist in the area.

When they found him his house was a large rambling place with guards and a fence around it, I think. After a little while talking to him and finally, after many questions and dragging of feet, they got the medicine, he asked them to do something for him which was like black market. The pharmacist's house was stuffed full of rusty machines, glassworks, paintings, etc. In this post-apocalyptic world, trade for items such as these was like money.The pharmacist was rich. The pharmacist was really hot on the woman. The couple are the main characters.

He is a white guy, rather rough-hewn in his early to mid-30s. She, I think, is white but some memory is triggering that she was darker, either light black or well tanned. She is probably in her early 20s. All this was not the main plot of the book, that was the quest they were on which I haven't the faintest idea now what that was. This was simply a most interesting part of the plot due to the unique use of pharmacists instead of doctors. It was an important part of the plot in that her injury delayed their quest significantly.

I don't remember that there was a specific time limit for them to achieve their end but I just remembered that they had to escape from the pharmacist. He was going to keep the woman and the man kinda sorta didn't like that idea :-). Once they escaped, there was a scene of them around the campfire while she drank the medicine and healed from her injury. I hope this helps and I thank you so much for your interest and assistance... –

The pharmacist would not give them the medicine until they completed the underworld task he had for them. The guy left to do it and the pharmacist started hitting on the woman and was about to rape her when the man came back in. He would have killed the pharmacist if they didn't need the medicine.

It is revealed at some point that the pharmacist is not really a pharmacist at all but a black marketeer. It seems he murdered a pharmacist and took all of his meds including a book that said what everything was used for. The woman's injury was, of course, infected and all she needed was a good strong antibiotic.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I read the book about three or four years ago. I got it from the library and it was just a single book, not part of a series. Instead of futuristic, a better description is post-apocalyptic. There's so very little I remember but I will go through the checklist and see if I job any more memory

Comment: It was not part of an anthology. The age range, due to the violence, was probably 14+. I remember how desperately they needed to find pharmacist. Pharmacists filled the role of doctors. There was one famous pharmacists in the area. When they found him his house was a large rambling place with guards and a fence around it, I think. After a little while talking to him and getting the medicine he asked them to do something for him which was like black market. The pharmacist was really hot on the woman.

Comment: I read this book about four years ago as an e-book from the library. I have no idea when it was published but it had the feel of a modern publication, late 1900s or post-2000. A better word for it than futuristic is post-apocalyptic. It was not part of an anthology. The Reader's age range, due to the violence, was probably 14+. I remember how desperately they needed to find a pharmacist because our heroine was injured. Pharmacists filled the role of doctors. There was one famous pharmacist in the area.

Comment: When they found him his house was a large rambling place with guards and a fence around it, I think. After a little while talking to him and finally, after many questions and dragging of feet, they got the medicine, he asked them to do something for him which was like black market. The pharmacist's house was stuffed full of rusty machines, glassworks, paintings, etc. In this post-apocalyptic world, trade for items such as these was like money.The pharmacist was rich. The pharmacist was really hot on the woman. The couple are the main characters.

Comment: He is a white guy, rather rough-hewn in his early to mid-30s. She, I think, is white but some memory is triggering that she was darker, either light black or well tanned. She is probably in her early 20s. All this was not the main plot of the book, that was the quest they were on which I haven't the faintest idea now what that was. This was simply a most interesting part of the plot due to the unique use of pharmacists instead of doctors. It was an important part of the plot in that her injury delayed their quest significantly.

Comment: I don't remember that there was a specific time limit for them to achieve their end but I just remembered that they had to escape from the pharmacist. He was going to keep the woman and the man kinda sorta didn't like that idea :-). Once they escaped, there was a scene of them around the campfire while she drank the medicine and healed from her injury. I hope this helps and I thank you so much for your interest and assistance...

Comment: Sorry for the repetition above. After discovering that I had too many characters I went and wrote it in word and ended up repeating myself. Note – the pharmacist would not give them the medicine until they completed the underworld task he had for them. The guy left to do it and the pharmacist started hitting on the woman and was about to rape her when the man came back in. He would have killed the pharmacist if they didn't need the medicine.

Comment: It is revealed at some point that the pharmacist is not really a pharmacist at all but a black marketeer. It seems he murdered a pharmacist and took all of his meds including a book that said what everything was used for. The woman's injury was, of course, infected and all she needed was a good strong antibiotic.

Comment: You should add these details to the original question.

Comment: I thought I had. Where do I go to copy/paste the above into my original question?

Comment: I still have added no leads on this book. Thought I'd just stir the pot a little. Anybody? Anything?